# how to embed a QR code with existing image using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, qr-code

i have a QR code and an existing image .In an existing image i want to embed the created QR code .Can any one help ? 
I am comfortable with nodeJS,JavaScript,jQuery

Comment: Are you wanting to do this client side or server side?

Comment: thank you so much.i am going through it.but there is a problem i really don't know what will be the  customer/user setup in terms of browsers.so is there any alternate of canvas ?

Comment: If you do end up going the server-side route check out this answer which uses nodeJS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070708/merge-2-images-with-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML canvas drawImage should help.

You may draw image over already drawed image.

More documentation you can find here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

---

As another solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#child{
    background: url('http://www.mobile-barcodes.com/images/small-qr-code.gif');
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgy6K/

---

But of course, the best solution is using server side for solve you problem

Comment: Thank you bro . any alternate in JavaScript ?

Comment: As far as i know, there no way to resolve your problem using pure JavaScript or JavaScript + JQuery

Comment: so if somebody using older browser which does not support canvas ? what will be alternative excluding JavaScript?

Comment: As i suggest, html and css, or most best way - solve your problem using server side

Comment: what if i want to insert child image  at particular position  in parent image ?

Comment: p.s. @ioseph post helpful comment for you question. It may help. About your comment - look this jsfiddle (if i understand you correctly) - http://jsfiddle.net/Tg7yB/2/

Comment: thank you guys . i got solution in nodejs
var images = require("images");

images("input.jpg")                     //Load image from file 
                                      
    .size(600)                
 .draw(images("download.png"), 50, 100)
.draw(images("index.png"),450,100)                                      
    .save("output.jpg", {               
        quality : 600                   
    });