# I would like to merge all images within DIV and allow user to download (js powered)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, canvas

I'm working on a client's web design and development powered by Wordpress and Woocommerce, the plugin is great but there's a few functions I wish it had. The main one is giving the ability for the user to save the preview of their configuration.

The plug-in is 'Woocommerce Visual Products Configurator':

It allows buyers to build their own item by selecting from a series of different attributes for different parts of an item. Ex, choosing different types of Soles for a shoe, as well as being able to choose from a series of laces for the same shoe.

**My Issue:** The configuration images are layered on top of each other as the user selects their options so any normal "save as" function will just save the top image.

I have succesfully managed to combine and save the images using html2canvas-Data URL() but the way it generates the screenshots means the quality becomes very poor.

My thoughts are to merge all the images within the "vpc-preview" DIV then force the download.

Hunting through the functions of the plugin I found this:

```
function merge_pictures($images, $path = false, $url = false) {
$tmp_dir = uniqid();
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$generation_path = $upload_dir["basedir"] . "/VPC";
$generation_url = $upload_dir["baseurl"] . "/VPC";
if (wp_mkdir_p($generation_path)) {
    $output_file_path = $generation_path . "/$tmp_dir.png";
    $output_file_url = $generation_url . "/$tmp_dir.png";
    foreach ($images as $imgs) {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgs);
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($imgs);
        imagealphablending($img, true);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);
        if (isset($output_img)) {
            imagecopy($output_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 500);
        } else {
            $output_img = $img;
            imagealphablending($output_img, true);
            imagesavealpha($output_img, true);
            imagecopymerge($output_img, $img, 10, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
        }
    }
    imagepng($output_img, $output_file_path);
    imagedestroy($output_img);
    if ($path)
        return $output_file_path;
    if ($url)
        return $output_file_url;
} else
    return false;
}
```

However the function isn't called anywhere. There's also a couple of "save" buttons that are commented out which makes me wonder if they removed from a previous build.

Ideally I'd like the user to be able to instantly share their creation to facebook but thought this would be a good start.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to use the following code to output an alert of the url's of each of the config images. Useless for the user but at least I know it's targeting exactly what I need.

```
function img_find() {
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#vpc-preview img');
var imgSrcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
}

return alert(imgSrcs);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to manipulate this and merge the corresponding image of each URL then force the download?

### [Cick to see Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feedthecreative/nnLzLxbh/5/)

**UPDATE 2:**  The following fiddle lets users upload images and then merges them into a single photo for download. Unfortunately my coding skills aren't good enough to manipulate this into using the SRC urls of images within certain DIV and to Merge all the photos on top of each other.

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feedthecreative/8kojcaza/4/)

```
function addToCanvas(img) {
// resize canvas to fit the image
// height should be the max width of the images added, since we rotate -90        degree
// width is just a sum of all images' height
canvas.height = max(lastHeight, img.width);
canvas.width = lastWidth + img.height;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
if (lastImage) {
    ctx.drawImage(lastImage, 0, canvas.height - lastImage.height);
}

ctx.rotate(270 * Math.PI / 180); // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.height, lastWidth);

lastImage = new Image();
lastImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
lastWidth += img.height;
lastHeight = canvas.height;
imagesLoaded += 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the images." Are you talking about configuration images, the item preview, or what?

Comment: Hi Jefre, by images I mean the configuration images in the preview. As the user selects the different options it will overlay the corresponding image that represents it.  It's what's seen in the preview that I'd like the user to be able to download. Thanks

Comment: I just need to use the SRC urls outputted from the first script and feed them into the second script to be merged for the download. I've no need for the merged image to be previewed in the canvas but it's simple enough just to hide the canvas via css.  The images are PNG with transparency to be merged on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070708/merge-2-images-with-node-js), I would take a look at [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? (StackOverflow is generally opposed to link only answers due to dead links, and such...)

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I've been looking at Javascript canvas's but am yet to find anything that uses almost unlimited images with various names. Frustrating because I know I'm not far off.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is use a @print css file to only capture the divs needed. Very simple concept but works well.

After looking at your link, that is exactly the situations I use it in..online designers. It is a little more difficult keeping your layers responsively aligned, but in the end I feel your codes become cleaner and it works well across devices and OS'.

If you dont want PDF and a simple preview and download than html2image.js is perfect.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

 $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
Place any code here
    </div>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>
```

For High quality you want to use rasterizeHTML.js

Found here:
https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js/blob/master/examples/retina.html

Comment: Hi Johnny, interesting idea! Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best. Would this allow me to have a "Save" button on the page that when clicked would result in a popup window to save the image? Because if so then I'll definitely look into it further.

Comment: You can but it would be a PDF and for me it is for an industry that requires high quality for print ready quality. So with that, I think a simple save as jpeg will work and I will post a jquery solution now in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to send that over Johnny. I've got html2canvas in place at the moment but because of the way it captures the images the resolution drops significantly (especially on retina). A PDF gives the high quality I would like (and will use for something else) but for the moment I'm looking for a high quality jpeg or png that the user can then post to social media. Which is why I want to try use the original src urls for each image.

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot with  rasterizeHTML.js and see what happens. The other issue is that the configurator is embedded with a shortcode that doesn't like being used anywhere but the default wordpress text editor. Which is another reason I'm looking for a solution that can just make use of the SRC urls generated on the page.