# Join 2 image in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image-processing

Can I join 2 image into 1 like:

[image]

Is there any nodejs lib supported?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [merge-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images).
I have never used it, so I don't sure about it.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I'll try it :)

Comment: You can use keyword `merge image nodejs` with google.

Example :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070708/merge-2-images-with-node-js

Answer (score 3):

You might need this: https://github.com/zhangyuanwei/node-images

Cross-platform image decoder(png/jpeg/gif) and encoder(png/jpeg) for Nodejs

```
images("big.jpg").draw(images("small.jpg"), 10, 10).save("output.jpg");
```